# iOS CGImage leak

Tags: ios, core-foundation, cgimage, cgimageref

[image]

I used Instruments Leak, and found something.In my project, I do some stitching job.Then resave with photo's exif. But I don't know where leaks?

Comment: Show how you work with CG* functions.